# Mongo C# driver update a specific element in a nested array

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

How do I modify in Mongo (C# driver) a single element in a nested property (array) without retrieving the whole document?

```
public class Element
{
    public int Value {get; set;}

    public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class Document
{

     public Element [] Elements {get; set;}
}
```

In example I want to find the element with name "Car" and sets its value to 4 in a single query.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need [$ positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) where you can specify document-level condition and array-level condition to find single nested item in an array of particular document. In C# `$` sign is represented by `-1` passed as an index of your model array. Try:

```
var col = mydb.GetCollection<Document>("collectionName");
var id = new ObjectId("5babaaf5509f6d342da5abaa");
var elementName = "Car";
var newValue = 2;

var filterBuilder = Builders<Document>.Filter;
var filter = filterBuilder.Eq(x => x.Id, id) &
    filterBuilder.ElemMatch(doc => doc.Elements, el => el.Name == elementName);

var updateBuilder = Builders<Document>.Update;
var update = updateBuilder.Set(doc => doc.Elements[-1].Value, newValue);

Col.UpdateOne(filter, update);
```

**Update:** -1 is not supported in MongoDB.Driver 2.19 in .NET 6, you'll get
`Expression not supported: x.Elements.get_Item(-1) because negative indexes are not valid. To use the positional operator $ use FirstMatchingElement instead of an index value of -1.` Just include that `using MongoDB.Driver.Linq` statement and replace the line above.

```
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;

var update = updateBuilder.Set(doc => doc.Elements.FirstMatchingElement().Value, newValue);
```

Comment: I need to update all elements where matches the filter. It will only update one element?

Comment: @HammadSajid yes, this will update only one, for multiple you can try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60219952/get-and-add-update-multilevel-embedded-nested-mongodb-document-using-c-sharp/60220666#60220666

Comment: That's very sweet of you, I am searching for hours' but not able to found it

Comment: "In C# $ sign is represented by -1 passed as an index of your model array" Learned this here, thank you!

Comment: So grateful for the update above, which solved my problem after hours of searching around the web. The official documentation really needs some love. `FirstMatchingElement` is exactly what I needed, and nice and clean too.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a generic method, this works as of driver version `2.23.1`. `T` is the parent doc and `C` is the sub/nested doc.

```
public async Task UpdateArrayItemAsync<C>(
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter, // eg. (parent => parent.Id == "1")
    Expression<Func<C, bool>> arrayFilter, // eg. (sub => sub.Id == "1a")
    string arrayField, // Name of the array field on the parent doc
    IDictionary<string, object> updates) // Fields and values to set on array object
{
    var updateFilter = Builders<T>.Filter.And(
        Builders<T>.Filter.Where(filter),
        Builders<T>.Filter.ElemMatch<C>(arrayField, arrayFilter));
    
    // '.$' refers to the first matched element in Builders<T>.Filter.ElemMatch<C>()
    var updateDefs = updates.Keys
        .Select(field => Builders<T>.Update.Set(
            $"{arrayField}.$.{field}", updates[field]));

    await _mongoCollection.UpdateOneAsync(updateFilter,
        Builders<T>.Update.Combine(updateDefs));
}
```